# Use php command instead of full path with xampp installation?

Tags: command-line, php, symbolic-link, paths, php-cli

I have Xubuntu installation and XAMPP installed on my PC, and everything works great. However, lately I am experimenting a little bit with Laravel framework and a lot of tutorials and people just use PHP command in terminal, but for me to work I have to load a full path like:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php
```

And the file in `bin/php` links to proper PHP version.

That works but I would like to speed up a process a bit and to use just `php` as everyone else use and it's much simpler than to use full path.

So my question is how to set a path so I can use just `php` in my terminal.

I have read a couple tutorials and there are suggests of setting a path in `~/.bashrc` or to use `export`.

But none of them works for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Have you tried symlinking the php binary from /usr/bin?

Assume your **XAMPP** installation is in default location `/opt/lampp`

This is the command to achieve that (in your case):

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Comment: I am getting this: `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/php': File exists`

Comment: @Chester remove the file and link again : `sudo rm /usr/bin/php`
then `ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/bin/php`  again

Answer (score 0):

Try sym-linking the PHP library from file and refer to this php file path `/usr/bin/php` wherever required.

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the `php-cli` package:

```
sudo apt install php-cli
```

If you already have PHP CLI installed, you have to use `update-alternatives` to set the system default.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```